# Input for either phone number or email HTML

Tags: html

I want to create an input field that can take either the user's phone number or email. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `<input type="text"/>`?

Comment: You can add both. But you should have these in different input fields, as they are very different in terms of validation. If you google it, you will find info about this on pages like https://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe precise your question because I don't know what do you really want.
But if you want to inform the user of the site, do this:

```
<input type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="Phone number or email">
The placeholder is the text by default in the input so the user can understand what does he must write.
```

Comment: I want to create an input field similar to Instagram's, such that the input field accepts only phone numbers or emails. Is there a way to do that using only HTML and CSS or does that require JavaScript?

Comment: It requires Javascript